# Animating SceneKit SCNNode position not working

Tags: ios, swift, animation, cabasicanimation, scnnode

I followed this exactly:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/animation/animating_scenekit_content

I have a SCNNode on another SCNNode that has the geometry of the user face.

The SCNNode that is on the face SCNNode, I would like the movement to be animated. I'm calling this function which is in a subclass of the SCNNode I want to animate. The property it takes is a location on the face. This function doesn't work at all:

```
 func move(to vertex: SCNVector3) {
  let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "move")
  animation.fromValue = SCNVector3(self.position.x, self.position.y, self.position.z)
  animation.toValue = vertex
  animation.duration = 3.0
  self.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "move")
 }
```

This function works perfectly fine:

```
 func move(to vertex: SCNVector3) {
  self.position.x = vertex.x
  self.position.y = vertex.y
  self.position.z = vertex.z
 }
```

The function call to both functions:

```
move(to: SCNVector3(anchor.geometry.vertices[Node.oldVertexPos].x, anchor.geometry.vertices[Node.oldVertexPos].y, anchor.geometry.vertices[Node.oldVertexPos].z))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyPath "move" doesn't exist on SCNNode, you should be animating the position.

`let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")`